# How to redirect after form post with scrapy_splash package?

Tags: python, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm using Python, Scrapy, Splash, and the scrapy_splash package to scrap a website.

I'm able to log in using the SplashRequest object in scrapy_splash. 
Login creates a cookie which gives me access to a portal page. To this point all works.

On the portal page, there is a form element wrapping a number of buttons. When clicked the action URL gets updated and a form submission is triggered. The form submission results in a 302 redirect.

I tried the same approach with the SplashRequest, however, I'm unable to capture the SSO query parameter that is returned with the redirect. I've tried to read the header Location parameter without success.

I've also tried using lua scripts in combination with the SplashRequest object, however, I'm still unable to access the redirect Location object.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I realize there are other solutions (i.e. selenium) available however the above tech is what we are using across a large number of other scripts and I hesitate to add new tech for this specific use case.

```
# Lua script to capture cookies and SSO query parameter from 302 Redirect
lua_script = """
    function main(splash)
        if splash.args.cookies then
            splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)
        end
        assert(splash:go{
            splash.args.url,
            headers=splash.args.headers,
            http_method=splash.args.http_method,
            body=splash.args.body,
            formdata=splash.args.formdata
        })
        assert(splash:wait(0))

        local entries = splash:history()
        local last_response = entries[#entries].response

        return {
            url = splash:url(),
            headers = last_response.headers,
            http_status = last_response.status,
            cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
            html = splash:html(),
        }
    end
    """

def parse(self, response):
    yield SplashRequest(
    url='https://members.example.com/login',
    callback=self.portal_page,
    method='POST',
    endpoint='execute',
    args={
        'wait': 0.5,
        'lua_source': self.lua_script,
        'formdata': {
            'username': self.login, 
            'password': self.password
        },
    }
)

def portal_page(self, response):
    yield SplashRequest(
    url='https://data.example.com/portal'
    callback=self.data_download,
    args={
        'wait': 0.5,
        'lua_source': self.lua_script,
        'formdata': {}
    },
)

def data_download(self, response):
    print(response.body.decode('utf8')
```

Comment: Hey, after logging in you're getting cookies; scrapy-splash should pass them to Scrapy (if configured correctly, i.e. all necessary options set). But your Lua script doesn't initialize cookies, so each Splash request is not authenticated in your example. Could you try making cookies work first? See https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#session-handling and a last example at https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#examples

Comment: Many thanks for your reply Mikhail. My understanding is that calling the SplashFormRequest.from_response method and passing in the response object will initialize the cookies and headers. Should I be using the SplashRequest object instead and manually setting the headers and cookies myself in the lua script?

Comment: The problem is in Lua code: cookies and headers are passed to the Lua script (SplashRequest / SplashFormRequest take care of it), but these values are not used in this script - e.g. there is no splash:init_cookes call. Check the example I linked to - it has all necessary pieces to enable all this stuff.

Comment: I'm now able to get and set cookies. Also able to follow the redirect and the SSO query parameter from the 302 redirect. I'm still having some issues with subsequent posts where I am running into issues with invalid sessions but I believe this specific question has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the question above with a working example.

I changed a few things however the problem I was having was directly related to missing the `splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)` reference.

I also converted from using `SplashFormRequest` to `SplashRequest`, refactored the `splash:go` block and removed a reference to the specific form.

Thanks again @MikhailKorobov for your help.

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting a `LUA_ERROR` on line 5 of your script... but I think it's correct. Could you double check? I'm using `Scrapy==1.4.0` and `scrapy-splash==0.7.2`

Comment: @GianfrancoP. Thanks for the message. I updated the code with a null check for the splash.args.cookies assignment to fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The problem seems to be with the `assert()` around the `go:{...}` function. For some reason when you have the full-form function, the assert doesn't work.

Comment: The assert in Lua will throw an error if the first argument is false or nil otherwise it will fail silently. From the code above if you remove only the `splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)` do you receive any errors? Is yes, then perhaps your issue is with the splash instance. I sometimes I need to restart the docker instance when I run into errors.